# Scope variable value is undefined outside resource service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have created angularJs factory service to dealing with REST calls.Service is worked fine.I have some cases that i need to set values in to $scope.variable and access them in outside of resource service.But i got undefined. I wrapped them inside angularJs `$q` but seems like i did some mistake.please help me to solve this.

**AngularJs Factory**

```
myApp.factory('MyService',function($resource) {

    return{
       GetMYData:$resource(my rest service URL, {});
      }

    });
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.myMap={};
$scope.promises=[];
$scope.myData = MyService.GetMYData.query();
            $scope.myData.$promise.then(function (result) {

            result.forEach(function(e, i) {
             //Do something
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              $scope.myMap[e.key]=e; //Put elements into map and i tried to access map from outside service by giving key

              deferred.resolve(result);
              $scope.promises.push(deferred.promise);
              $scope.myMap[$location.search()['dataID']] //This display the actual value
            })
    ...
}
```

If URL parameter present in the URL i do the following things.

```
if($location.search()['dataID']){

   $q.all($scope.promises).then(
   function(data) {
          console.log($scope.myMap[$location.search()['dataID']]) // throws      undefined
    },function(response) {
         //Handle if promises are rejected
        })
}
```

Please let me know how can i access the map values set by angularJs resource service from outside of service.

Answer (score 0):

What I'll try to do is:

```
     myApp.factory('MyService',function($resource) {




 var _resource = $resource(my rest service URL, {},{
             query:{method:"GET",IsArray:true}
       })


            return{
               GetMYData:function(){
                       return _resource.query();
                      }
              }

            });
```

then:

```
$scope.myMap={};
$scope.promises=[];
 MyService.GetMYData.$promise.then(function (result) {

            result.forEach(function(e, i) {
             //Do something

              $scope.myMap[e.key]=e; //Put elements into map and i tried to access map from outside service by giving key



              $scope.myMap[$location.search()['dataID']] //This display the actual value
            })
    ...
}
```

and then access simply your

```
if($location.search()['dataID']){

  console.log($scope.myMap[$location.search()['dataID']]) );

}
```

Comment: i tried this but map is empty when accessing outside of the service thats why i used promises to wait until resolved.

Comment: sorry but are you using the service just only to retirve data..the  you put the data in the $scope.myMap in the same controller wher you access it?